# OAuth1 empty "authentication" in /wp-json

Tags: wp-api, oauth

I'm trying to get a Meteor based app to login to WordPress using WP API OAuth1 plugin on the WordPress side. I've actually gotten pretty far with the standard `/oath1` end points, which are all working. But the last step is giving me trouble.

As far as I can tell I've installed and set everything up correctly, and set up the "application" correctly, but I don't see anything information about the service in /wp-json. It's just an empty array:

`"authentication": [],`

Is there some other step I need to do to get it working?

Comment: If you now try to access an endpoint in a way that requires authentication, what happens?

Comment: I'm not actaully sure how to do that. If I append the auth_token I just get a